# Difference in MD5 hashing output for Python3 hashlib and Google BigQuery

Tags: python, hash, google-bigquery

Running the following query in Google BigQuery gives this output: `SfaKXIST7CwL9ImCHCH8Ow==`

```
select md5( "hi" )
```

Running the code for MD5 hashing in Python however gives a different output:
`49f68a5c8493ec2c0bf489821c21fc3b`

```
import hashlib
hashlib.md5( b"hi" ).hexdigest()
```

Since they are both using the same algorithm, shouldn't the output's also be the same ? What is the reason for the difference here ?

Also in the [BigQuery Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#hash-functions), the code generates a digest, not a hexdigest, but when I execute the command in BigQuery, it gives out a hexdigest.

Comment: The first output seems to be base64 encoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, big query outputs the digest by encoding it in base64.

```
import hashlib
import base64
print base64.b64encode(hashlib.md5(b'hi').digest())
```

The above output should match the output from `bigquery`.
I'm not sure why google outputs it base 64 encoding although the docs don't mention it.